# store null as default value againt Null boolean field

Tags: python, django, sqlite

How to use `NullBooleanField` in `Django` models with `SQLlite3`,
I want to store `null` as default value for the `nullBoolean` field, how do I do that?

I have migrated db from `BooleanField` to `NullBooleanField`, but it is still storing False as the default value.

Usage in the code is as:

```
LOCATOR_YES_NO_CHOICES = ((None,''), (True,'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
employed = models.NullBooleanField(choices=LOCATOR_YES_NO_CHOICES,
                                max_length=3,
                                blank=True, null=True, default="",)
```

Any example would be of great help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An empty string `""` is not `None`

```
>>> "" is None
False
```

If you want the default to be `None` then write:

```
employed = models.NullBooleanField(choices=LOCATOR_YES_NO_CHOICES,
                                max_length=3,
                                blank=True, null=True, default=None,)
```

Comment: After making default=None, I'm getting "IntegrityError at /intake/locator/" which tells me that:
"intake_locator.employed may not be NULL"
but the field is defined as NullBooleanField.

Comment: Did you checked in the database, whether employed field will accept NULL? otherwise you might need to alter the table.

Comment: Changing the field type in your model will not alter the table in your database automatically. You will need to drop it and run `syncdb` again, or use tools like `south` for automated schema migration.

Comment: I have made null=True for the field,
also I have used south for schema migration.
Now running  python manage.py schemamigration intake --auto
is giving "Nothing seems to have changed."

Comment: @user3269734, you might need to manually change the database schema. South does a good job, but sometimes it misses things.

Comment: Note that for NullBooleanField, the default is `blank=True, null=True`, so you don't need to specify that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#NullBooleanField

Answer (score 6):

Note that `NullBooleanFIeld` was **[deprecated](https://djangodoctor.medium.com/nullbooleanfield-is-dead-7d3fc286ed6e)** in `Django 3.1`. It is recommended to use `BooleanField(null=True)`.

In this case;

```
employed = Models.BooleanField(null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: Agree that using `BooleanField` is the better move. Django 4.x will be out soon with RC1 having just come out. And at that point in time, `NullBooleanField` will be dead unless someone is planning on running an old (insecure) version of Django forever, which is not good. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: The default value of `BooleanField` is `None` when `default` isn’t defined.
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield)